# How to secure laptop other than BIOS Password?

Tags: encryption, lenovo-laptop, disk-encryption

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T560 with kali linux directly installed on HDD, i have seen many youtube videos that even BIOS password can be tampered & reset, even if the disk is encrypted they can replace a new drive, so is there any other strong encryption method that i can use on my laptop to secure so in case if its stolen that will make laptop useless.

Comment: No there is not, if they have the laptop they can remove any safeguards to use the laptop.

Comment: Well, there sort of is a method: CompuTrace. If it’s built into your system, is as secure as it gets.

Comment: You can encrypt the drive blocking access to your data.  Unless the guess/brute force your encryption password.  You can't prevent the user from changing hard drives and resetting the BIOS password.

Comment: @moab I agree that this appears the case on this laptop, but some laptops do/did have systems baked into the bios and processor - googlev"Intel anti theft" for more. Unfortunately according to https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/devices-systems/laptops/standard/lenovo-thinkpad-t560-H30985854.html this laptop dies not support it.

Comment: Your question precludes the best answer: Lock the laptop in a box and don't let it get stolen in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. But I think the question needs a bit more discussing.

What **exactly** are you trying to secure? The entire laptop or only the hard drive? If you want to secure the entire laptop, then you have BIOS password, operating system's log on password, different other encryption programs which require passwords, etc. No method is 100% thief proof, but at least he'll have something to work for. Or, you can take the physical approach in taking the laptop with you everywhere, including shower and sleep.

If you try to secure the hard drive (the content on it, to be precise), then I think the best methods are:

1. Get an external HDD, put the important data on it and carry it with you. Then the laptop can be stolen;
2. Cloud storing. Google Drive, OneDrive, etc. Only you know the password, don't store it anywhere except your brain. Again, everything else can be stolen.

Comment: I think the question wants to secure the laptop from further use rather than the data.

Comment: That is nearly impossible to do tho.

Comment: Which makes me wonder why is this laptop so important.